# Is it possible to merge two video files to one file, one screen in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video, avfoundation

I'm new to video programming. I'm trying to exercise it but I'm having trouble, which merges two video files to one.

The merge I mean is as follows..

**I have first video like this**
[image: enter image description it i]

**Second video also like this**
[image]

**I want them to merge like this**
[image]

I didn't want to use 2 video players because I want to send the merged video file to someone. I searched all day to solve this, but I could't find how to.

I wrote code referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757423/ios-video-editing-is-it-possible-to-merge-side-by-side-not-one-after-other-t) link but it shows first video only, not merged.

**My Code:**

```
NSURL *firstURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"]]
AVURLAsset  *firstAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:firstURL options:nil];

NSURL *secondURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"]];
VURLAsset  *secondAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:secondURL options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration)
                    ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration)
                     ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                      atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[secondTrack setPreferredTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.25f,0.25f)];

NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *outputFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo.mov"]];

NSLog(@"%@", outputFilePath);

NSURL *outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];


AVAssetExportSession* assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

[assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: ^(void ) {

     switch (assetExport.status) {
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
             NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
             NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
             break;
         case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
             NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
             break;
         default:
             break;
     }
 }
 ];
```

What am I missing? I don't know how I can approach this to solve the problem.

Appreciate any ideas.
Thanks.

**Edit:**

i made a new code which referenced a link matt wrote, thanks matt. but when i tried to export it, only first video was exported. not together.. :(

my new code is..

```
NSURL *originalVideoURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video1" withExtension:@"mov"];
NSURL *originalVideoURL2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"video2" withExtension:@"mov"];


AVURLAsset *firstAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:originalVideoURL1 options:nil];
AVURLAsset *secondAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:originalVideoURL2 options:nil];

AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init]; //[AVMutableComposition composition];

NSError *error = nil;
AVMutableCompositionTrack *firstTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[firstTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[firstAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

if(error) {
    NSLog(@"firstTrack error!!!. %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

AVMutableCompositionTrack *secondTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[secondTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[secondAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

if(error) {
    NSLog(@"secondTrack error!!!. %@", error.localizedDescription);
}


AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration);

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *firstLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:firstTrack];
CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.7, 0.7);
CGAffineTransform move = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(230, 230);
[firstLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(scale, move) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *secondLayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:secondTrack];
CGAffineTransform secondScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2, 1.5);
CGAffineTransform secondMove = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
[secondLayerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(secondScale, secondMove) atTime:kCMTimeZero];

mainInstruction.layerInstructions = @[firstLayerInstruction, secondLayerInstruction];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
mainCompositionInst.instructions = @[mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(640, 480);

AVPlayerItem *newPlayerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:mixComposition];
newPlayerItem.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;

AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:newPlayerItem];

AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];

[playerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
[player play]; // play is Good!!


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *tempS2 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FinalVideo.mov"];

if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:tempS2])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:tempS2 error:nil];
}


NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: tempS2];

AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                       initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exportSession.outputURL=url;

NSLog(@"%@", [exportSession supportedFileTypes]);

exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
    if (exportSession.status==AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"failed");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"AudioLocation : %@",tempS2);
    }
}];
```

how can i export my mixComposition and layerInstruction both?

please give me a little more ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: But did you look at the discussion here: https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/ ? The key is the use of AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction, and I don't see you doing that anywhere.

Comment: thanks your comment matt. but i have a trouble when i export the final file. could you give me a little more hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the code in your second edit, just as you've told the `AVPlayerItem` about your `AVMutableVideoComposition`, you need to also tell the `AVAssetExportSession` too:

```
exportSession.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;
// exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler etc
```

**N.B.** make sure you choose the longer of the two track durations when setting your instruction duration:

```
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMaximum(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration));
```

`AVPlayer` doesn't mind if you get this wrong, but `AVAssetExportSession` does and will return an `AVErrorInvalidVideoComposition` (-11841) error.

**N.B. 2** Your `AVPlayer` isn't actually going out of scope, but it makes me nervous when I look at it. I'd assign it to a property if I were you.

Comment: HI @Rhythmic Fistman, How are you... I need your help, seriously... I'm stuck in the same Question... I have to show the video side by side after merging... Both Videos are showing BUT not showing properly like side by side... Need your help... Thanks

Comment: You should start question with your code and a screenshot of the incorrect output

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Actually i'm unable to Post a Question right now because I'm reached my Question limit... Hope you understand... Thanks